# ArcGIS Desktop tool that does for records in a table what "Dissolve" does for features?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, attribute-table, dissolve

I have a data table that I need to trim down, merging records which have the same value in an ID field and performing a couple math operations on various other fields (summing, averaging). The Dissolve tool in ArcGIS does this for feature classes, but it doesn't work on tables. I realize there's probably a tool in ArcGIS that does this (it's basically a Dissolve with no geometry) but I haven't found it and am in a bit of a hurry.

Is there one? I have an ArcInfo license available if necessary.

Comment: See this related question, specifically Justin's answer and Dan Patterson's comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19383/select-distinct-values-from-a-single-column-of-an-attribute-table-or-layer

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do this with the [Summary Statistics (Analysis) tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001z000000.htm). The **case** field parameter is what you use to "dissolve". From the above link:

> case_field [case_field,...] (Optional)
>   The fields in the Input Table used to calculate statistics separately for each unique attribute value (or combination of attribute values when multiple fields are specified).

Comment: This answer is correct for the specific question; however, I want to provide a warning to those who may be looking to dissolve without any statistics fields: it won't work. You must submit a statistics field. If you're looking to "dissolve" a table but not calculate summary statistics, then you can use the Delete Identical tool. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/delete-identical.htm

Answer (score 8):

This sounds like you need to look at the [Summary Statistics](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001z000000.htm) tool which I find to be a bit of a Swiss Army Knife in that it comes with a Basic (formerly called) ArcView level license and can often be used in place of Frequency (that needs Advanced/ArcInfo) and PULLITEMS (that needs ArcInfo Workstation:-) to reorder fields.

Answer (score 1):

The Dissolve_management tool works on tables as well as feature classes.

Comment: ? In arcgis desktop 10.3.1 I get an _"One or more dropped items were invalid and will not be added to the control."_ error. (ArcToolbox >> Data Management Tools >> Generalization >> Dissolve)