# Merge rule missing in ArcCatalog?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.3, merge

When trying to use the 'Merge' tool in ArcCatalog [EDIT (v. 10.3.1)], I am not seeing all of the merge rules- the options I can select are different than those outlined in the tool's 'About' section. Can anybody tell me why this might be? In particular I would like to use the 'Join' rule to create an output merging individual records with corresponding field values without just appending one table onto the end of another as is currently happening.

In the image below, you can see from the dropdown merge rules which are available in contrast to those that the tool is telling me should be available on the right. The order is different and 'Range' appears to have replaced 'Join'. Do these tools perform the same function?

[image]

Comment: Check the options in the drop-down against a Text field rather than a Number field.  I think they differ and may be why you don't see what you're expecting

Comment: @Midavalo I think that you are spot on : please write your comment as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the options in the drop-down against a *Text field* rather than a *Number field*. They differ and may be why you don't see what you're expecting.

**Text field merge options:**
[image]
**Number field merge options:**
[image]

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense- although I'm still lost as to how to use the merge tool to collapse related records from multiple tables!

Comment: I think perhaps you are after the [Dissolve]( http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/dissolve.htm) tool rather than the Merge tool?

Comment: I looked into Dissolve as an option but won't allow input of the tables I am using as they are not spatial features. Essentially there are three tables, related by one field which I need to bring together. Make Query Table seems to do what I need but I am then having trouble turning the Table View output into a memory-written table- but I think I will start a separate thread to try and resolve this.

Comment: Ah!  You original question doesn't specify tables rather than feature classes.  Take a look at [Table equivalent to Dissolve for features in ArcGIS for Desktop?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19714/table-equivalent-to-dissolve-for-features-in-arcgis-for-desktop)